# multiple where in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I want to get results from the products table that cat_id = [1,2,3] AND sub_id = [7,8]
I use the following code but it doesn't work for me properly

```
$cat=[1,2,3];
$sub=[7,8];
$products = Product::whereIn('cat_id', $cat)->whereIn('sub_id',$sub)->latest()->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Your query is correct and should work. What is not working for you?

Comment: Depending on where you want the work to be done, there are 2 options. But since you want this to be handled purely database side you'll need to use a join for that query - https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#joins

Comment: it should work ! is it give any error ? Please show us

Comment: Please add the errors which you faced with.

Comment: @Adam  Yes it is right and it works
The problem was with another part of the code